# How can I push a personal git repository on Launchpad?

Tags: git, launchpad

Launchpad lets you do something like this:

```
bzr push ~user/+junk/mybranch
```

And it will create a `junk` bzr branch.

I would like to do the same using a git repository. Is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no separate place for "junk" branches in git versus repositories for projects.

You just add a remote of `git+ssh://USER@git.launchpad.net/~USER/+git/` and push to that, as per the [Launchpad Help on Git](https://help.launchpad.net/Code/Git#Configuring_Git).

Comment: This is incorrect.  The ~user/+git/... namespace is exactly equivalent to the ~user/+junk/... namespace for Bazaar branches, just with a different name.  In particular it is *not* the same as repositories for projects, which live under the ~user/project/+git/... namespace.